# When does a functor commute with colimits?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Is it true that an additive functor between abelian categories commutes with colimits if it's right-exact and commutes with (arbitrary) direct sums?

If yes, does someone know a good source of a proof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a category with coproducts and coequalizers, any colimit can be built out of coproducts and coequalizers. This is a nice exercise. In an $\text{Ab}$-enriched category, coequalizers can be replaced with cokernels. This is another nice exercise.

Comment: In other words, the answer is *yes*. :-)

Comment: The answer is yes provided that the source category is cocomplete. Otherwise one might take "commutes with colimits" to mean "commutes with all colimits that exist in the source category" and then who knows?