# The example of an exact functor that doesn't commute with colimits in abelian category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

It is mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848790/when-does-a-functor-commute-with-colimits) that a right exact funtor commute with colimits only under some good conditions.

I wonder if there is a concrete counterexample of an exact functor which doesn't commute with colimits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the functor $\text{Hom}(M, -)$ where $M$ is, to keep things concrete, an $R$-module and Hom takes values in abelian groups. This functor is exact iff $M$ is projective but commutes with colimits iff $M$ is finitely generated projective. So a counterexample is given by any projective module which is not finitely generated, for example an infinitely generated free module $\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} R$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could be please show a proof of "but commutes with colimits iff $M$ is finitely generated projective" or some reference containing this result? I haven't seen it before...

Comment: And by the way, I am asking for an exact functor, not just right exact...

Comment: @Ti Wen: $\text{Hom}(M, -)$ is automatically left exact, so it's right exact iff it's exact. You can find a proof here: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/05/07/tiny-objects/ But you don't need this proof to understand the counterexample, you can just verify directly that the functor I wrote down doesn't commute with e.g. infinite coproducts.